# can i get two mode (statistics)?

Tags: python, statistics

I have an error here

```
import statistics 
data=[5, 8, 15, 7, 10, 22, 3, 1, 15,10]
print (statistics.mode(data))
```

Can I get two mode in Python?

Comment: _I have an error here_ What error? _Can I get two mode in Python?_ What does that mean?

Answer (score 1):

For a simple solution, and a *short list*, you can use [`collections.Counter`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html):

```
from collections import Counter

top2 = Counter(data).most_common(2)
# [(15, 2), (10, 2)]
```

To get the second mode, you could then do:

```
top2[1][0]
# 10
```

---

Though for *long lists*, it might be more convenient to do the following:

```
n = 2
l = data[:]
for _ in range(1, n+1):
    nth_mode = statistics.mode(l)
    l.remove(nth_mode)

nth_mode
# 10
```

Answer (score 0):

You can handle the error using try:except clause;
Then work your way to find the number of modes in your dataset.

```
import statistics 
data=[5, 8, 15, 7, 10, 22, 3, 1, 15, 10]
try:
    print (statistics.mode(data))
except:
    print ("No unique mode found")
    from collections import Counter
    cmn = Counter(data).most_common()
    maxCnt = cmn[0][1]
    modes = [t[0] for t in cmn if t[1]==maxCnt]
    print('Num of modes: ', maxCnt, 'Modes: ', modes)
```

Result:

```
No unique mode found
Num of modes: 2    Modes:  [15, 10]
```